# how to extract string after any character

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have data shown below. I'd like to extract the last part after the last underscore.
The data before the underscore can be any length but written with the same syntax i means : letters_letters_letters.
So i wrote this code to extract the part after the last underscore then it's works perfectly but i noticed that there is 2 names written differently like (letters_letters-letters )
with - instead of _ at the end.

```
NAME= (SELECT SUBSTRING('''+@NAME+''', CHARINDEX(''_'','''+@NAME+''',CHARINDEX(''_'','''+@NAME+''')+1)+1, CHARINDEX(''_'','''+@NAME+''') + CHARINDEX(''_'','''+@NAME+''',CHARINDEX(''_'','''+@NAME+''')+1)) FROM TABLE)
```

My question is : is there away to check or extract string after any character (without specify if it's underscore or other) ?

Can anyone help please.

Column name is like :

BOB_LOU_K

the thow others columns are like :

BOB_LOU-K

Thanks

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, sorry but my question is clear i would like to extract the last part of the string after the last underscore input : BOB_LOU_K output : K then this part is ok it's works with the above code. now i would like to know if is there away to extract string after any character (without specify if it's underscore or other) cause i have 2 names like BOB_LOU-K not the underscore at the end

Comment: Can you use `replace` function inside your substring.

Comment: How do you know the dash isn't part of the name you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that finds the position of the last character that is not a letter and return the substring from that position to the end of the string. Call that function on your query, something like this `SELECT Col1, [dbo].[fn_GetLastString](Col1) AS lastString FROM mytable` your function fn_LastString would look somehing like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION fn_GetLastString(@cSearchedExpression VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pos INT = LEN(@cSearchedExpression)
    DECLARE @currentChar VARCHAR(1) 
    DECLARE @lastString VARCHAR(MAX)

    WHILE @pos>0
    BEGIN
        SET @currentChar = SUBSTRING(@cSearchedExpression, @pos, 1)
        IF NOT (@currentChar LIKE '[a-Z ]' )
        BEGIN
            SET @lastString = SUBSTRING(@cSearchedExpression, @pos, LEN(@cSearchedExpression) - @pos + 1)
            BREAK; 
        END

    SET @pos = @pos - 1
END

RETURN @lastString
END
GO
```

p.s. notice the space in `'[a-Z ]'` that will include spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
select txt
      ,right(txt, patindex('%[^a-zA-Z]%', reverse(txt) + ' ') - 1) as last_token
  
from   (values ('BOB_LOU_K'), ('BOB_LOU-K'), ('Yet-aonther-badly-written-question'), ('*followed*by*mediocre*answers'), ('at~best'), ('Quite depressing'), ('isn''t it?'), ('Yep')) t(txt)
```

| txt | last_token |
| --- | --- |
| BOB_LOU_K | K |
| BOB_LOU-K | K |
| Yet-aonther-badly-written-question | question |
| *followed*by*mediocre*answers | answers |
| at~best | best |
| Quite depressing | depressing |
| isn't it? |  |
| Yep | Yep |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cjknjz--)

Answer (score -1):

A a minimal reproducible example is not provided. So, I am shooting from the hip.

If there are some additional characters to take care of, just add them to the *@junkChars* variable.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES 
('BOB_LOU_K'),
('BOB_LOU-K'),
('Yet-aonther-badly-written-question'), 
('*followed*by*mediocre*answers'), 
('at/the\best'), 
('Quite depressing'), 
('isn''t it?'), 
('Yep');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '_'
   , @junkChars VARCHAR(10) = '-*\ ';;

SELECT t.* 
    , result = c.value('(/root/r[last()]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)')
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(TRANSLATE(tokens, @junkChars, REPLICATE(@separator, DATALENGTH(@junkChars))), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| ID | tokens | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BOB_LOU_K | K |
| 2 | BOB_LOU-K | K |
| 3 | Yet-aonther-badly-written-question | question |
| 4 | *followed*by*mediocre*answers | answers |
| 5 | at/the\best | best |
| 6 | Quite depressing | depressing |
| 7 | isn't it? | it? |
| 8 | Yep | Yep |